# Display new image on Tkinter button command

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Using `Tkinter`,How can I toggle between images when a button is click. Having this code as reference, I can only load one image but I don't know how to make it behave the way I need.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def showImage(*args):
        lbl['image'] = image_tk

root = Tk()   
c = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(5, 5, 12, 0))
c.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

fname = "A.jpg"
fname1 = "B.jpg"
image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fname))

btn = ttk.Button(c, text="load image", command=showImage)
lbl1 = ttk.Label(c)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5)
lbl.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I configure my `ShowImage` function or any other modification needed to be able to switch the image between `fname` and `fname1`

Comment: What research have you done? Have you read the documentation on methods for widgets (such as the configure method)?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have read some of the documentation but I have not come across the configure method. would you mind referening to a link where i can read more about it. I dont mind doing it on my own if I have a good resourse.

Comment: two common sources of documentation are http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method and http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html

Comment: Thanks, this might be enough info to do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change images on button clicks use the `configure()` method to the button to change the command argument and create a new `ImageTk` object to hold a reference of the second image.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image    

def showImage():
        lbl1.configure(image=image_tk)
        btn.configure(text = "load image!", command=showImage1)

def showImage1(): 
        lbl1.configure(image=image_tk1)
        btn.configure(text = "load image!", command=showImage)     

root = Tk()    
c = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(5, 5, 12, 0))
c.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

fname = "a.jpg"
image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fname))

fname1 = "b.jpg"
image_tk1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fname1))  # new image object


btn = ttk.Button(c, text="load image", command=showImage)
lbl1 = ttk.Label(c)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5)
lbl1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's odd that you use `configure` sometimes, and the dictionary syntax in others. Your example might be a bit less confusing if you used just one syntax or the other.